# Iteration Problem Facebook Bot / Transforming text file lines into an array

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, bots

I'm trying to make a bot for Facebook. I have to log in to facebook with a username and password (found in identifiants.txt). After, I do actions on facebook, I log out and I have to log in again with other username and password. 
Each line corresponds to a username and the next line corresponds to a password. So the next line is still a username. What I've tried to do is to transform the text file into a table of usernames. So the usernames have an odd box and the passwords have an even box. So here's what I tried to do:

```
nombre_listeux = 2

class Facebook(scrapy.Spider):

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver
    self.url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'
    webdriver.maximize_window()

def login(self,nombre_listeux):

    f=open("/Users/anthonyjacquelin/Desktop/Dev Projects/Bot Insta /Facebook Bot/identifiants.txt","r")

    for i in range(0,nombre_listeux):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        lines=f.readlines()
        print(i)
        username=lines[2*i]
        password=lines[2*i+1]
        print(username)
        print(password)
        user = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"email\"]")
        user.send_keys(username)
        pwd = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"pass\"]")
        pwd.send_keys(password)
        sleep(medium_time)
        Facebook_Bot.change_pic(nombre_listeux)
        Facebook_Bot.log_out()

    f.close()
```

The program works for the first pair of identifiers and for i=0, but when i=1, this is what the program returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/anthonyjacquelin/Desktop/Dev Projects/Bot Insta /Facebook Bot/facebook.py", line 68, in <module>
Facebook_Bot.login(nombre_listeux)
File "/Users/anthonyjacquelin/Desktop/Dev Projects/Bot Insta /Facebook Bot/facebook.py", line 29, in login
username=lines[2*i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Identifiants.txt is also like that :

```
dermacareprofr@gmail.com
password1
legrandpatrick410@gmail.com
password2
```

It would be awesome if you could help me, thanks !

Comment: Using any such automation tools that interact with the website directly, is against Facebook’s ToS. If you need to automate anything - then you should do it via the provided APIs. (And if those don’t allow for what you want to do, then you should not do it at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to get data from your text file

```
nombre_listeux = 2
with open('/Users/anthonyjacquelin/Desktop/Dev Projects/Bot Insta /Facebook Bot/identifiants.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i in range(0, nombre_listeux):
    username = lines[2 * i].strip()
    password = lines[2 * i + 1].strip()
    print(username)
    print(password)
```